# Java Swing Frame Object calling another one, first one freezes while the second one executes and shows nothing until when it's done

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

Basically I have two classes, each one uses their own frame and works separately. The first one, for this example, is just a button that when pressed calls a new instance of the second one. The second one is a game that runs by itself okay and updates the frame correctly when called alone.

When the button is pressed, a new instance of the game is created and the game occurs but nothing is showing up on its frame. But when the game ends, both frames work correctly and show what they should.

I was thinking of using threads but I'm not sure on how to do it because I want to stop button while the game occurs and when the game ends, continue the button class.

Here are some pictures showing what's going on:

Button from the first object:
[image: Button from the first object]

When clicked (the button won't work again and the game runs but does not show anything):
[image: Second object does not update and show anything]

After the game ends (both objects work fine and only the results are shown in the game object):
[image]

The code from the first object just in case, even though it works just fine:

```
        ActionListener StartGame = e -> {
            new Game(Octopi,1); //Variables needed to start the game
        };

        JButton bX = new JButton();
        ...
        bX.addActionListener(StartGame);

        frame.add(bX);
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Search the site for other questions that talk about "freezes" and concentrate on answers the talk about `blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Code invoked from a listener executes on the EDT which would imply you have blocking code in your Game class, probably since you have a continuous loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it working in case anyone else finds it useful:
[This page](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming) explains Asynchronous Programming in Java, I used the first example given and it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you are developing with Swing, you need to understand how the Event Dispatch Thread works to avoid a lot of problems down the line. See https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077754/swing-threading-and-the-event-dispatch-thread.html?page=5 for example.